# How to install sm_market theme in magento 2.3.6

Tags: theme, installation, file, zip, magento2.3.6

How to insatll sm_market theme in magento2.3.6. I want to install it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the official SM Theme documentation for this. Check this link:
http://documentation.flytheme.net/sm-magetheme/

Or Check Magento documentation regarding this:

**To install a theme manually**:

- Make sure that the directory structure you are copying is
  /. And all the theme files are in the 
  directory.
- Copy this directory to the /app/design/frontend
  directory.

> For detailed info check this:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-install.html

Comment: I have extrat magento 2.3.6 into magento_project directory..Now where have I to extract sm_market_quickstart_pl_m2.4.0_v6.2.0 this. shall I create the new folder like sm_market and have to exratct theme there..or exactly in which place i have to extarct the sm_market_quickstart_pl_m2.4.0_v6.2.0 files?

Comment: I have read the document and I am not getting where have to extract the sm_market_quickstart_pl_m2.4.0_v6.2.0 .

Comment: @SonaliGhule please refer to support guide provided for **sm_market** theme http://documentation.flytheme.net/sm-market-24/

Comment: @SonaliGhule, First extract the theme zip file on your local side and then upload all data from "app/design/frontend" to the same path as your Magento root "app/design/frontend". And all data from "app/code" upload then same path as your Magento root "app/code". If the "code" directory not there then first create "code directory inside the "app" directory and then upload.

Comment: Thank You @AmitSaini  .It saves my time.

Comment: Welcome @SonaliGhule, Feel free to upvote and accept the answer.